# if I install Ubuntu on my Macbook will the apple logo still light up?

Tags: macbook, apple, keyboard-backlight, logo

I have a Macbook and would like to know if and when I install ubuntu on it will the apple logo on the back of the screen still turn on?

Comment: You can always boot from a LiveUSB and check.

Comment: rather not as I am away for now but when I get around to it I will try it out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a MacBook with a glowing logo, yes. The light for the logo is active so long as the screen is active regardless of what operating system you’re using.

Comment: Thank you very much, and does it still pulse?                            
                                                                     
        #sorry I have an Idea to turn the light into a 
        purple ubuntu light and would like to know

Comment: I’ve never seen the  logo pulse or change colour except on modified notebooks used by DJs. None on my MacBooks over the years have done this, either.

Comment: Thank you all very much, This has been very helpful.